# Uninstaller checking if a task was selected during the installation

Tags: inno-setup

How would one check, at the time of uninstalling, if a task checkbox was selected during the installation, using Inno Setup?

Comment: In the registry check the uninstall key of your program. There is a string value called "Inno Setup: Selected Task" which contains the selected tasks

Comment: Well, you can post it as an answer, because you're clearly right :D But, is there any better or cleaner way to do it instead of getting the string from the registry and cutting it around commas?

Comment: Or if not, a way to get the installation registry path depending on system architecture?

Comment: `RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\appid_is1", "Inno Setup: Selected Tasks", Value) or RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, ...)` will do on any architecture.

Comment: If you want a better answer, you should tell us what are you actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Martin and anotheruser, your comments have already solved my problem.

Comment: You can use the `IsTaskSelected` function if you're writing a `Check` function for some uninstaller section entry.

Comment: Why did you remove your answer, TLama? I was going to try your solution and maybe accept your anwser.

Comment: @TLama Can you please send me your answer or post it here because I need the sample code you provided :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IsTaskSelected`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_istaskselected) function if you're writing a [`Check`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck&anchor=Check) function for some uninstaller section entry. The [`IsTaskSelected`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_istaskselected) function cannot be called at uninstaller runtime, but you can use it there because the [`Check`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck&anchor=Check) parameter values for uninstall sections are evaluated when the installer creates the uninstall log at the end of the installation. So you can do this:

```
[Tasks]
Name: mytask; Description: "Task"; GroupDescription: "Tasks"

[UninstallRun]
...; Check: IsTaskSelected('mytask')

[UninstallDelete]
...; Check: IsTaskSelected('mytask')
```

But you cannot call it at uninstaller runtime, so this will fail to execute:

```
procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm;
begin
  if IsTaskSelected('mytask') then // <- this will fail to execute
    ...
end;
```

To determine the task state at uninstaller runtime you can query the `Inno Setup: Selected Tasks` registry value as was mentioned in comments.